# Converting a list containing a binary number to decimal and hexadecimal in scheme

Tags: list, binary, scheme, hex, decimal

I'm pretty new to scheme. I know how to convert from decimal to binary but I can't come with the logic of converting the other way around. I want to get a decimal number from a list of binary numbers.

Example of decimal:

```
(decimal '(1 0 1)) ---> 5
```

Example of hexadecimal:

```
(hexadecimal '(1 0 0 0 1)) ----> 12
```

So far I think it can be done taking the last number of the list and multiply it recursively by 2<sup>i</sup> where i represents the position in the list so the last number is multiplied by 1, the next one by two, and so on. Finally add these numbers on each recursive cycle. Dont know how to execute this idea nor if it will work.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear about the ordering of the binary digits in the input list, and the input examples do not help to clarify. Consider the input `'(1 0 0)`. Now, what is the last number of the list, and what is the first? I'd say 0 is the last and 1 the first. Not multiply those by 2^i where i is the position of a number in the list. The first number is at position 0, and the last is at position 2, yes? Then we have 1*2^0 + 0*2^2 = 1. Or, The first number is at position 2 and the last number is at position 0, so we have 1*2^2 + 0*2^0 = 4. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

The inputs in the spec are unclear, however assuming the OP wants to convert a binary number read left to right, we need to reverse the order of digits first so that the first car we take is the least significant bit; with each subsequent power of 2 applied to the next significant bit.  In order to handle the reversing inside the function one can use a named let which allows us to recurse the body of the let only, after we have reversed the list.  One way of doing this in Guile Scheme is shown below:

```lisp
(define (binary->decimal binary-list)
  "Calculate decimal equivalent of list of binary"
  (let loop ((rev-bl (reverse binary-list)))
    (if (null? rev-bl)
        0
        (+ (car rev-bl) (* 2 (loop (cdr rev-bl)))))))
```

Comment: Rather than asserting that another answer is wrong and then stating that the input needs to be reversed and named `let` employed, it might be better to discuss why the input needs to be reversed, and why named `let` is needed. Of course, there are other ways to solve the problem too. Also, FYI, Scheme does not have docstrings; better to use comments since they are not evaluated.

Comment: It really isn't clear that the other answer is wrong, since OP was unclear about the ordering of binary digits in the input list. I'm voting to close this question as "_Needs details or clarity._"

Comment: Yes fair point because the OP has used numerical examples which are palindromic, the spec is unclear.  Although most people would assume binary is read left to right in the absence of spec.  I will update my comment to highlight this, and explain the named let usage.  Note docstrings are part of Guile - I will clarify that my answer is Guile Scheme.

Comment: It was a good catch, and I agreed with you at first, but a list of binary digits might be supplied reversed for various reasons (i.e., the list need not be a direct representation of a binary number). I suspect that OP got a bit backwards when describing their proposed algorithm, but I don't think that we will hear back from them. I forgot about Guile docstrings; I use them in Common Lisp, but they aren't standard in Scheme or Racket, and my preferred Scheme (Chez) doesn't have them. IAC, +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Your written description of the solution is correct — all you need to
do is execute it.  A couple of pointers:

- the logic is much easier if you reverse the list
- passing the weight of each digit and the accumulated sum as
  arguments to your recursive function makes it simpler

You are on the right track — keep trying.  A pseudocode attempt might
make it clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun bin-list-to-dec (lst)
  (reduce (lambda (x y) (+ (* x 2) y)) lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(define (binary->natural lon)
  (if (null? lon)
      0 
      (+ (car lon) (* 2 (binary->natural (cdr lon))))))
```